# Reduce line continuation in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make excel create XML files using VBA (that my first time), so I managed to create a code but I keep getting the message that there are too many line continuations

Here is my code

```
Sub testXLStoXML()
 sTemplateXML = _
    "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + _
"<offers>" + vbNewLine + _
"   <offer>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_identifier>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_identifier>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_title>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_title>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_description>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_description>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_featured_image>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_featured_image>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_cat>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_cat>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_location>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_location>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_tags>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_tags>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_type>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_type>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_start>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_start>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_expire>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_expire>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <offer_store>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </offer_store>" + vbNewLine + _
"           <!-- store  -->" + vbNewLine + _
"           <store_title>" + vbNewLine + _
"           </store_title>" + vbNewLine + _
"           <store_letter>" + vbNewLine + _
"           </store_letter>" + vbNewLine + _
"           <store_description>" + vbNewLine + _
"           </store_description>" + vbNewLine + _
    "           <store_logo>" + vbNewLine + _
"           </store_logo>" + vbNewLine + _
    "           <store_link>" + vbNewLine + _
"           </store_link>" + vbNewLine + _
"           <store_facebook>" + vbNewLine + _
"           </store_facebook>" + vbNewLine + _
"           <store_twitter>" + vbNewLine + _
"           </store_twitter>" + vbNewLine + _
"           <store_google>" + vbNewLine + _
"           </store_google>" + vbNewLine + _
"           <!-- store  -->" + vbNewLine + _
"       <!-- DEAL RELATED -->" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_items>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_items>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_item_vouchers>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_item_vouchers>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_price>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_price>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_sale_price>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_sale_price>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_discount>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_discount>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_voucher_expire>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_voucher_expire>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_in_short>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_in_short>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_type>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_type>" + vbNewLine + _
"       <deal_link>" + vbNewLine + _
"       </deal_link>" + vbNewLine + _
"   </offer>" + vbNewLine + _
"</offers>" + vbNewLine +
```

Is there a way to bypass the limit or make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Microsoft, "There is a limit to the number of lines you can join with line-continuation characters. This error has the following cause and solution:
Your code has more than 25 physical lines lines joined with line-continuation characters, or more than 24 consecutive line-continuation characters in a single line. Make some of the constituent lines physically longer to reduce the number of line-continuation characters needed, or break the construct into more than one statement."

The line continuations are merely for ease of reading the code and are necessary to have after each tag the way you have it now

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to make the lines longer?

Comment: Why are you splitting the content over so many lines? You could place both the opening and closing tags on the same line for example, or combine multiple lines into longer ones.

Comment: "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine +  "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + "<offers>" + vbNewLine + "   <offer>" + vbNewLine +

Comment: The _ is the line continuation.    Just put several parts on one line removing the _